# How do i reset, update or clear the offset of each consumer group for a topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a topic let's say as test001 and supposed there is 10000 messages in topic . I have two consumer group's lets say test-group1 and test-group2 for consuming the message from the above topic.

If test-group1 consumer's has consumed 4000 message and test-group2 consumer's has consumed 4500 message so how can i do:

1. Reset the offset to 0 of test-group1 consumer group?
2. update the test-group1 consumer groups offset to 4500?
3. delete the message from topic and reset offset of all consumer group to 0?

Comment: What did you find in the documentation of Kafka about these questions?

Comment: Nothing was specified properly in the apache kafka's official docs .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reset the offset at consumer group level. You can use the `seek` method (in the Java client API) to move to the start of the partition (offset 0), end or any other offset of your choice. Try exploring some of the CLI options such as kafka-consumer-groups.sh, kafka-topics.sh

Comment: do you have any CLI options ?

Comment: From what I can recall, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

This ticket shows that one can produce directly to the __consumer_offsets topic to overwrite the offsets, using the special "__admin_client" id:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5246

I'm not familiar with the format of the __consumer_offsets topic messages. This post may help a bit but you'd need to do more digging yourself:

http://dayooliyide.com/post/kafka-consumer-offsets-topic/

It may be simpler to write an app that given your group id does a seek to the given position and commits the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Offsets are stored for each topic+partition+group.id, not overall for the entire topic. You cannot delete committed offsets, only commit newer ones, or wait for them to expire from the _consumer-offsets topic (default of 24 hours).

In 0.11 there will be an offset management tool so you can change offsets from the CLI independently from the consuming apps.